# Remove powered by in iframe widget - display none and css not work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a website and added a chat widget but want to display none on some part of this widget/iframe. The widget is loaded in an iframe with .js file and HTML trigger.

I can in Chrome Developer Tools use this code to get away the things I want but I can not get this to work on the live site.

```
.ember-view .footer-note {
    display: none!important;
}
```

HERE IS CODE I WANT TO DISPLAY NONE

```
<div id="ember123" class="ember-view footer-note">⚡ by <a href="https://somelink.com/" class="product" target="_blank">the link</a>
</div>
```

How do I do to load my CSS code after maby 5 secounds after all page have been loaded?

I have tested this but doesn't work:

```
$(window).load(function() {
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//www.linktoCSSwhereDisplayNoneIs.se/css/style.css">');
});

$('iframe').contents().find("div[comp='ember*']").remove();
```

And the css

```
*[id^='ember-']{
display: none!important;
}
div[class^="ember"], div[class*=" ember"] {
    color:red 
}
.ember-view .footer-note {
    display: none!important;
}
```

Comment: Probably you are using their free service. Upgrade your account to remove it. Removing it is not ethical.

Answer (score 0):

Probably we can try appending the style after the iframe has loaded.

```
$("#iframe-id").on("load", function () {
    $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//www.linktoCSSwhereDisplayNoneIs.se/css/style.css">');
});
```

Comment: I use Wordpress so was change $ to jQuery but it does not seams to work anyway. Only works in when I put display none in Chrome Dev tools.

Comment: The iFrame ID looks like this <iframe id="fc_widget" name="fc_widget" title="Chat" frameborder="0"></iframe> Dont know if I do correct if I do like this `jQuery("#fc_widget").on("load", function () {
    jQuery('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//www.site.com/css/style.css">');
});`

Comment: What you think?  :)